# Check whether a field from a line of text line matches a value

Tags: perl

I have been using the following Perl code to extract text from multiple text files. It works fine.

Example of a couple of lines in one of the input files:

```
Fa0/19    CUTExyz     notconnect   129         half    100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/22    xyz MLS     notconnect   1293        half     10 10/100BaseTX
```

What I need is to match the numbers in each line exactly (i.e. `129` is not matched by `1293`) and print the corresponding lines.

It would also be nice to match a range of numbers leaving specific numbers out i.e.  match 2 through 10 but not 11 the 12 through 20

```perl
#!/perl/bin/perl

use warnings;

my @files = <c:/perl64/files/*>;

foreach $file ( @files ) {

    open( FILE, "$file" );

    while ( $line = <FILE> ) {
        print "$file $line" if $line =~ /123/n;
    }

    close FILE;
}
```

Thank you for the suggestions, but can it can be done using the code structure above?

Comment: What does `/n` mean?

Comment: It seems it's a new thing in 5.22, that prevents  groups from capturing. But given the OP has no groups, I'd assume it's a typo.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to show some examples of lines that should and shouldn't be matched?

Comment: I have edited your code to add indentation. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Sensible indentation is an important tool to help people to understand your code, and it you are asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, it is surely only polite to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: By far the easiest way to format code is using `perltidy -pbp`. This is a tool worth using anyway, but doubly so if you want to post code somewhere :)

Comment: In regex: `/^123$/` but `eq` as in the answer seems more appropriate.

Comment: Only if it's 'exact match on the whole line' rather than 'match numbers on the line'.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you take a look at [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

You need to anchor your regex pattern. The easiest way is probably using `\b` which is a zero-width boundary between alphanumerics and non-alphanumerics.

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $file ( glob "c:/perl64/files/*" ) {
   open( my $input, '<', $file ) or die $!;
   while (<$input>) {
      print "$file $_" if m/\b123\b/;
   }
   close $input;
}
```

Note - you should use three-argument `open` with lexical file handles as above, because it is better practice.

I've also removed the `n` pattern modifier, as it appears redundant.

Following your edit though, to give us some source data. I'd suggest the solution is *not* to use a regex - your source data looks space delimited. (Maybe those are tabs?).

So I'd suggest you're better off using `split` and selecting the field you want, and testing it numerically, because you mention matching ranges. This is not a good fit for regexes because they don't understand the numeric content.

Instead:

```
while ( <$input> ) {
   print if (split)[-4] == 129;
}
```

Note - I use `-4` in the `split`, which indexes from the *end* of the list.
This is because column 3 contains spaces, so splitting on whitespace is going to produce the wrong result unless we count down from the end of the array. Using a negative index we get the right field each time.

If your data is tab separated then you could use `chomp` and `split /\t/`. Or potentially split on `/\s{2,}/` to split on 2-or-more spaces

But by selecting the field, you can do numeric tests on it, like

```
if $fields[-4] > 100 and $fields[-4] < 200
```

etc.

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary; the regex `/\b123\b/` matches the line "123 is the new 456".

Comment: @tripleee: And, looking at the (now added) sample input, that's the behaviour the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you don't get the answers you're asking for, which discard best practice because of your unfamiliarity with Perl. It is inappropriate to ask how to write an ugly solution because *proper Perl* is beyond your reach

As has been said repeatedly on this site, if you don't know how to do a job then you should hire someone who does know and pay them for their work. No other profession that I know has the expectation of getting quality work done for free

Here's a few notes on your code. Wherever you have learned your techniques, you have been looking at a very outdated resource

- Do you *really* have a root directory `perl`, so that your compiler is `/perl/bin/perl`? That's very unusual, and there is no need to use a *shebang* line in Windows
- You *must always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare all of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. For some reason you do this with `@files` but not with `$file`
- It is better to replace `<c:/perl64/files/*>` with `glob 'C:/perl64/files/*'`. Otherwise the code is less clear because Perl overloads the `<>` operator
- Don't put variable names inside double quotes. It is unnecessary at best, and may cause bugs. So `"$file"` should be `$file`
- Always use the three-parameter version of `open`, so that the second parameter is the open mode
- Don't use global file handles. And *always* test whether the file has been opened correctly, dying with a message including `$!`—the *reason* for the failure—if the `open` fails

  ```
  open( FILE, "$file" )
  ```

  should be something like

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!}
  ```
- Don't rely on regex patterns for everything. In this case it looks like `split` would be a better option, or perhaps `unpack` if your records have fixed-width fields. In my solution below I have used `split` on "more than one space", but if your real data is different from what you have shown (tab-delimited?) then this is not going to work

  Note that `Fa0/129` will also be matched by your current approach

This Perl program filters your data, printing lines where the fourth field `$lines[3]` (delineated by more than one whitespace character) is numerically equal to `129`

The output shown is produced when the input is the single file `splitn.txt`, containing the data shown in your question

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for my $file ( glob 'C:/perl64/files/*' ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /\s\s+/, $line;
        print "$file $line" if $fields[3] == 129;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
splitn.txt Fa0/19    CUTExyz     notconnect   129         half    100 10/100BaseTX
```

Comment: tried your code.. didn't work...  thanks for the telling off by the way really helpful on   a free web site...       "if you don't know how to do a job then you should hire someone who does know and pay them for the work"

Comment: @normbeef: Then your description of the problem is lacking. I demonstrated that my code works with the *two lines* of data that you provide, and it's clearly impossible to do better unless you're more forthcoming. *"Didn't work"* is completely useless for diagnostic purposes, but I am not surprised: as I said, it is very unclear how your data is delimited, and I wrote was something that worked for your erroneous example.

Comment: @normbeef:  It's far from obvious why you quoted my *"if you don't know how to do a job then you should hire someone who does know and pay them for the work"*. Do you disagree with me? What do you do when you can't fix your car, or your house is falling down? Do you think a software engineering task is worthless?

Comment: @normbeef: The error can only be in the format of the data. If you want to pursue this then you can copy and paste some *real* data onto something like [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) and share the link here, but showing lines of characters that look something like what you really have is useless. It's my guess that the fields are tab-separated, but there are no tabs in the data that you have posted. There's also a possibility that the records have fixed-width fields, in which case `unpack` is the tool of choice. Getting arrogant and self-important about being criticised won't fix things.

Comment: Please lets get this straight.. I certainly do not think software engineering is not important or worthless, but this website is an open forum, it is far from that I promise you. I cannot understand the depth of the answers that might seem second nature to you, I have cobbled this together (as you can see) and I am aware that I need to explain the job better. my script is poor but its all I have that works for me.  I was really hoping to just get away it, as this project doesn't really require 1000% accuracy, its more of a management report.  I will try to go back over it and clarify again.

Comment: @normbeef: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum. Its primary function is as a repository of solutions to software engineering problems, and it is best to think of writing a question as being equivalent to creating a Wikipedia page, which I think you would take much more care over. I realise that you are here just to get a solution to your own problem, but the rest of the world sees it very differently. It is inappropriate to ask us to regurgitate the appropriate part of the language documentation for you, and to request low-quality answers within your own custom parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. When you say:

> What I need is to match numbers in the on each line exactly

That could mean a couple of things. It could mean that each line contains nothing but a single number which you want to match. In that case, using `==` is probably better than using a regular expression. Or it could mean that you have lots of text on a line and you only want to match complete numbers. In that case you should use `\b` (the "word boundary" anchor) - `/\b123\b/`.

If you're clearer in your questions (perhaps by giving us sample input) then people won't have to guess at your meaning.

A few more points on your code:

- Always include both `use strict` and `use warnings`.
- Always check the return value from `open()` and take appropriate action on failure.
- Use lexical filehandles and 3-arg version of `open()`.
- No need to quote `$file` in your `open()` call.
- Using `$_` can simplify your code.
- `/n` on the match operator has no effect unless your regex contains parentheses.

Putting that all together (and assuming my second interpretation of your question is correct), your code could look like this:

```
#!/perl/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = <c:/perl64/files/*>;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  open my $file_h, '<', $file
    or die "Can't open $file: $!";

  while (<$file_h>) {
    print "$file $_\n" if /\b123\b/;
  }

  # No need to close $file_h as it is closed
  # automatically when the variable goes out
  # of scope.
}
```

Comment: Hello Dave,  many thanks for the reply your are correct that I need to match the string within a row / line but print the whole line..   I have tried this code and it works very well.  it does however add what appears to be an additional line between the print output.

Comment: I want to ask an additional question related to this, but not sure whether or not to ask a new question as I appear to be in trouble on this site.  I need to also start matching more than 1 value on each row:  i.e. search and match value 1 & 2 before printing the line.

Comment: @normbeef: Yes, there's no need to explicitly print a newline as the `$_` will already have a newline in it. Sorry about that, but it's a simple enough fix.

Comment: @normbeef: If you have a new question to ask, then post a new question. But try to solve the problem yourself first.